# Selecting the row before the resultset in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

so lets say i have a table called `data`

### data

```
id | date      | name
---------------------    
1  | 19/8/2010 | John    
2  | 19/8/2010 | Mary    
3  | 20/8/2010 | Peter    
4  | 20/8/2010 | Bert     
5  | 20/8/2010 | Ernie
```

---

if i do a select statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM data where date = '20/8/2010';
```

is it possible to edit this select statement to take the row before it as well. in this case it returns me row number 3 - 5. but is is possible to edit the sqlstatement in any way to select row 2 as well?

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting row 2 in this case?

Comment: no criteria im afraid :\

Comment: @Kenneth: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: im not quite sure of wat DBMS means but im using sqlite

Comment: How did you know it was row 2 you wanted then, if there is no criteria?!

Comment: i just want a row that is before the actual set of rows to be selected as well

Comment: im afraid i cant in this case. sort of like a wildcard thingy. is there any way to detect the current row, then selecting the 1 before it as well?

Comment: If it doesn't matter whether the 'extra' row is John or Mary, or some other row with a date before 20/8/2010, or in some cases no row if no rows have a date 'before' your specified date, you could union another set (of a single row, perhaps using "SELECT TOP 1...") to your results. But I think there are other problems here in the design and logic of what you're doing that need to be addressed first...

Comment: I think what we want to know is when you say "before", by what columns is the data sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [@SteveCav's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528118/sql-select-statement-selecting-a-row-before-the-initial-select-statement/3528161#3528161) to `UNION` with the original query:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM   data d
JOIN   (
          SELECT MIN(id) lowest_id
          FROM   data 
          WHERE  date = '20/8/2010'
       ) dt ON (dt.lowest_id - 1 = d.id)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM   data 
WHERE  date = '20/8/2010';
```

Test case (tested in sqlite 3):

```
CREATE TABLE data (id int, date date, name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO data VALUES (1, '19/8/2010', 'John');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (2, '19/8/2010', 'Mary');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (3, '20/8/2010', 'Peter');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (4, '20/8/2010', 'Bert');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (5, '20/8/2010', 'Ernie');
```

Result:

```
id          date        name      
----------  ----------  ----------
2           19/8/2010   Mary      
3           20/8/2010   Peter     
4           20/8/2010   Bert      
5           20/8/2010   Ernie
```

This is assuming that by "the row before", you intend the row with the previous `id` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, iv used this as the ideal answer. Really appreciate it guys.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about SQLITE, but for SQL Server, for example, I might do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM data where date < '20/8/2010' ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC)
UNION
SELECT * FROM data where date = '20/8/2010'
;
```

This assumes that your criteria for "the row before" is the row with the largest date < the date you queried for, and if more than one row have that date, then grab the one with the max id.

Comment: SQLite supports the `LIMIT` syntax

Comment: Noting of course that in some cases with some dates and with some data, there will be no rows returned by the SELECT TOP 1 part.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select d.* 
from data d, 
(SELECT min(id) As LowestID FROM data where date = '20/8/2010') m
where d.id=m.LowestID-1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Id, [Date], Name
From MyTable
Where [Date] = '2010-08-20'
Union All
Select Id, [Date], Name
From MyTable
Where Id = (
            Select Max(T2.Id)
            From MyTable As T2
            Where T2.[Date] < '2010-08-20'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is close to what you want:

```
 SELECT * FROM data where date <= '20/8/2010' order by date desc;
```

and then stop reading from the result after you have the first row before August 20.

Answer (score 0):

Once the above query result is available in the current list then you can access any of the returned rows with a cursor.